# Argument of type 'UserType | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am new to typescript. Can someone please help explain what is going on here?

Here are my typescript errors

```
$ tsc
app/(auth)/register.tsx:5:11 - error TS2339: Property 'signIn' does not exist on type 'UserType | null'.

5   const { signIn } = useAuth();
            ~~~~~~

app/(auth)/sign-in.tsx:5:11 - error TS2339: Property 'signIn' does not exist on type 'UserType | null'.

5   const { signIn } = useAuth();
            ~~~~~~

app/index.tsx:6:11 - error TS2339: Property 'signOut' does not exist on type 'UserType | null'.

6   const { signOut } = useAuth();
            ~~~~~~~

context/auth.tsx:34:30 - error TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

34 export function AuthProvider(props) {
                                ~~~~~

context/auth.tsx:37:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'UserType | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserType'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserType'.

37   useProtectedRoute(user);
                       ~~~~


Found 5 errors in 4 files.
```

I made a context `context.auth.tsx`

```
import { router, useSegments } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';

type UserType = {}

const AuthContext = React.createContext<UserType | null>(null);

// This hook can be used to access the user info.
export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}

// This hook will protect the route access based on user authentication.
function useProtectedRoute(user: UserType) {
  const segments = useSegments();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === '(auth)';

    if (
      // If the user is not signed in and the initial segment is not anything in the auth group.
      !user &&
      !inAuthGroup
    ) {
      // Redirect to the sign-in page.
      router.replace('/register');
    } else if (user && inAuthGroup) {
      // Redirect away from the sign-in page.
      router.replace('/');
    }
  }, [user, segments]);
}

export function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [user, setAuth] = React.useState<UserType | null>(null);

  useProtectedRoute(user);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        signIn: () => setAuth({}),
        signOut: () => setAuth(null),
        user,
      }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

`app/_layout.tsx`

```
import { SafeAreaProvider, initialWindowMetrics } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Slot } from 'expo-router';
import { AuthProvider } from '@/context/auth';

export default function Root() {
  return (
    // Setup the auth context and render our layout inside of it.
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Slot />
      </AuthProvider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

`register.tsx`

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useAuth } from '@/context/auth';

export default function Register() {
  const { signIn } = useAuth();
  // signIn() will sign the user in
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text onPress={() => signIn()}></Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

`app/index.tsx`

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { useAuth } from '@/context/auth';

export default function Index() {
  const { signOut } = useAuth();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text onPress={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them like you are now! The errors are self explanatory. `useAuth()` can return null according to that type. If it returns null, your code will error at runtime, because you can't do `const { signIn } = null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/(auth)/register.tsx:5:11 - error TS2339: Property 'signIn' does not exist on type 'UserType | null'.
>
> 5   const { signIn } = useAuth();

This is because you have this context:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext<UserType | null>(null);
```

Which you have declare has a value of type `UserType | null`.

Then you make a hook that just gets the value from that context

```
export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Which then returns `UserType | null`.

And that type has no `signIn` property, so you get the error.

If you want the context to have this value:

```
      {
        signIn: () => setAuth({}),
        signOut: () => setAuth(null),
        user,
      }
```

Then you need it to have value type like that includes those properties. I'm guessing something like

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext<{
  signIn(): void
  signOut(): void
  user: UserType | null
}>({
  signIn: () => undefined,
  signOut: () => undefined,
  user: null,
});
```

---

> context/auth.tsx:34:30 - error TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> 34 export function AuthProvider(props) {

This is because function parameters require types in Typescript, and you have provided none.

The only prop you use here is `children`, so you can just declare that one.

```
// Note that object destructuring is conventional for react props.
export function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  //...
}
```

---

> context/auth.tsx:37:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'UserType | null' > is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserType'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserType'.
>
> 37   useProtectedRoute(user);

This is you declared `useProtectedRoute` to take a `user: UserType` parameter.

```
function useProtectedRoute(user: UserType) {
  //...
}
```

But the state you setup here:

```
const [user, setAuth] = React.useState<UserType | null>(null);
```

Says `user` is `UserType | null`. That means that `user` might be `null`, but the function your are passing it to doesn't handle `user` being `null`.

You either need to make `useProtectedRoute` take `UserType | null`

```
function useProtectedRoute(user: UserType | null) {
  //...
}
```

Or you need to make sure that `user` is not `null` before you pass to this function.

```
// This is sound typescript code but bad react code
const [user, setAuth] = React.useState<UserType | null>(null);
if (user) {
  useProtectedRoute(user);
}
```

NOTE: Because this a react hook, this will not work. You are not allowed to invoke a hook conditionally. I only include it here for illustrative purposes as an example if this was a normal function.